# CSS filter blur gets not applied as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div />` which is under my `<p />` tag. I apply a `filter: blur(5px);` to this `<div />` and I woudl expect the text to blur. However, this is not happening. When I apply a `background-color: red` to the `<div />`, the whole screen becomes red. Why is this not working with `filter`. Please note, I cannot move the `<div />` up in the hierachy, it must stay where it is.

```css
#filter {
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed vestibulum ex, a convallis lacus. Nulla ac nisi in erat viverra congue nec vel sapien. Phasellus sollicitudin commodo ipsum auctor bibendum. Morbi molestie nisl vitae condimentum porttitor. In in ipsum nec felis rutrum aliquet. Nulla vel euismod arcu. Proin porta dolor congue mauris bibendum, non interdum neque tempor. Nulla eu maximus risus. Aenean eu eros nisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi sagittis sed nisl ut venenatis. Aenean eu egestas metus. Curabitur nisi nisi, pharetra eget varius sed, varius ac urna.

Nam volutpat id justo et molestie. Praesent scelerisque porta lorem eget vehicula. Sed molestie nisi non risus blandit, at pharetra leo feugiat. Cras vitae massa ut nibh malesuada lacinia at vel nisi. Phasellus nunc odio, faucibus ac est eget, tempor ullamcorper ex. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Curabitur felis eros, rutrum ornare mi at, fringilla malesuada libero. Donec ultrices iaculis accumsan. Praesent efficitur, lacus eu iaculis euismod, risus ipsum tempor orci, nec vulputate eros leo et neque. Curabitur sodales non est quis lacinia. Fusce id ultrices orci. Mauris non dui eget magna volutpat facilisis vel nec velit. Mauris interdum enim quis pellentesque congue. Phasellus quis diam pellentesque, gravida nunc tempus, faucibus sem.
 </p>
  <div id="filter" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Answer (score -2):

Your filter id is on the wrong element. The content you want to manipulate must generally be contained within the element your css targets.

```css
#filter {
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="filter">
  <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed vestibulum ex, a convallis lacus. Nulla ac nisi in erat viverra congue nec vel sapien. Phasellus sollicitudin commodo ipsum auctor bibendum. Morbi molestie nisl vitae condimentum porttitor. In in ipsum nec felis rutrum aliquet. Nulla vel euismod arcu. Proin porta dolor congue mauris bibendum, non interdum neque tempor. Nulla eu maximus risus. Aenean eu eros nisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi sagittis sed nisl ut venenatis. Aenean eu egestas metus. Curabitur nisi nisi, pharetra eget varius sed, varius ac urna.

Nam volutpat id justo et molestie. Praesent scelerisque porta lorem eget vehicula. Sed molestie nisi non risus blandit, at pharetra leo feugiat. Cras vitae massa ut nibh malesuada lacinia at vel nisi. Phasellus nunc odio, faucibus ac est eget, tempor ullamcorper ex. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Curabitur felis eros, rutrum ornare mi at, fringilla malesuada libero. Donec ultrices iaculis accumsan. Praesent efficitur, lacus eu iaculis euismod, risus ipsum tempor orci, nec vulputate eros leo et neque. Curabitur sodales non est quis lacinia. Fusce id ultrices orci. Mauris non dui eget magna volutpat facilisis vel nec velit. Mauris interdum enim quis pellentesque congue. Phasellus quis diam pellentesque, gravida nunc tempus, faucibus sem.
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You and OP just need to know difference between `filter` and `backdrop-filter`, no need to change structure

Comment: As I said, I cannot move the `<div />` above the `<p />` tag!